# Yii removing index.php using htaccess gives me 404 error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, yii

I removed index.php from my url using htaccess as mentioned in Yii forums/guide.It was working fine on my Windows PC with Xampp installed in it.But when i uploaded it in on y shared hosting only home page is loading.All the other links are getting 404 error.

My .Htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . index.php
```

When i contacted my hosting  support team they told mode_rewrite is enabled.

My main.config content is

```
'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
            'rules'=>array(
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',

                'gii' => 'gii/<controller>',

                'admin' => 'admin/default/index',
                'admin/<controller:\w+>' => 'admin/<controller>',
                'admin/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'admin/<controller>/<action>',
                'admin/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'admin/<controller>/<action>',

                'gii' => 'gii/default/index',
                'gii/<controller:\w+>' => 'gii/<controller>',
                'gii/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'gii/<controller>/<action>',
                'gii/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'gii/<controller>/<action>',


            ),
            'showScriptName'=>false,
        ),
```

I tried numerous solutions,but all in vain.Please help

Comment: Have you found solution?? i got same problem

Answer (score 0):

Try `RewriteRule . /index.php` instead, watch the starting slash.

Otherwise the path is relative, so `http://somedomain.com/path/` would be redirected to `http://somedomain.com/path/index.php`, instead of `http://somedomain.com/index.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Url manager in config file must be like this

```
        'urlManager' => array(
        'urlFormat' => 'path',
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' =>  array(
                'home' => '/site/index',
                'cms' => '/site/contentview',
                'register' => '/site/register',
                'login' => '/site/login',
            ......),
    ),
```

And the .htaccess must be like this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

The most common problem when copying from localhost (windows or Mac) to sever (linux) is the case sensitivity, check your case on the controllers.

Also, check for the `AllowOverride` directive inside the definition of your virtualhost.

```
<Directory /path/to/website>
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

otherwise the rewrite rules will have no effect even when `mod_rewrite` is enabled.

Source: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/30739-404-errors-on-apache2-ubuntu/page__p__148021__hl__404+error#entry148021

Answer (score 0):

i experienced the same problem, check if you are following the naming convention of the controller **M**y**C**ontroller the first lettre and the "C" of controller must be capitalized.